# need select from two fields, unique in first based on highest of second

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with three fields,  an ID, a Date(string), and an INT.  like this.

```
+---------------------------
+BH|2012-09-01|56789
+BH|2011-09-01|56765
+BH|2010-08-01|67866
+CH|2012-09-01|58789
+CH|2011-09-01|56795
+CH|2010-08-01|67866
+DH|2012-09-01|52789
+DH|2011-09-01|56665
+DH|2010-08-01|67866
```

I need to essentially for each ID, i need to return only the row with the highest Date string.  From this example, my results would need to be.

```
+---------------------------
+BH|2012-09-01|56789
+CH|2012-09-01|58789
+DH|2012-09-01|52789
```

Comment: _Why_ are your dates stored as a string?  This is a **terrible** idea (although at least they're in a sortable form here).  And what have you tried so far?  And what if there are duplicate dates?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.id, t.date_column, t.int_column
    FROM YourTable t
        INNER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(date_column) AS MaxDate
                        FROM YourTable
                        GROUP BY id) q
            ON t.id = q.id
                AND t.date_column = q.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, date, int
FROM (  SELECT id, date, int
        FROM table_name
        ORDER BY date DESC) AS h
GROUP BY id
```

Replace table_name and columns to the right ones.

Comment: I reread the post and was about to do the same thing, lol...GMTA

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE  `stackoverflow`.`table_10357817` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Code` char(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The following query will wield the expected results:

```
SELECT Code, Date, Number
FROM table_10357817
GROUP BY Code
HAVING Date = MAX(Date)
```

The GROUP BY forces a single result per Code (you called it id) and the HAVING clauses returns only the data where it matches the max date per code/id.

**Update**

Used the following data script:

```
INSERT INTO table_10357817 
    (Code, Date, Number)
VALUES 
    ('BH', '2012-09-01', 56789),
    ('BH', '2011-09-01', 56765),
    ('BH', '2010-08-01', 67866),
    ('CH', '2012-09-01', 58789),
    ('CH', '2011-09-01', 56795),
    ('CH', '2010-08-01', 67866),
    ('DH', '2012-09-01', 52789),
    ('DH', '2011-09-01', 56665),
    ('DH', '2010-08-01', 67866)
```